# PowerShell 'Get-TeamChannelUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying Get the Channels users, using the following PowerShell Comments

```
$ChannelUser=Get-TeamChannelUser -GroupId $GroupId -DisplayName $ChannelName
```

It throws an error: **The term 'Get-TeamChannelUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.**

I have installed the following teams package

```
Install-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

Answer (score 1):

You did install it, but did you import it to your PS-session?

Check your current session using *Get-Module*

And if not loaded, simply: *Import-Module MicrosoftTeams*

**Update**

Seems like the cmdlt `Get-TeamChannelUser` is still in development and are only included in the public preview version.

[Add-TeamChannelUser](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-docs-powershell/blob/master/teams/teams-ps/teams/Add-TeamChannelUser.md)

However, you should be able to [install the latest public preview version](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-install#install-teams-powershell-public-preview).

> **Install Teams PowerShell public preview**
>
> If you're using the Public Preview version of Teams PowerShell, we
> strongly recommend that you first uninstall Skype for Business Online
> Connector.
>
> Installing the Teams PowerShell public preview module for all users on
> a system requires elevated privileges. Start the PowerShell session
> using Run as administrator in Windows or use the sudo command on macOS
> or Linux.
>
> If you're using PowerShell 5.1, you must update the PowerShellGet
> module beforehand. After you update PowerShellGet, close and reopen an
> elevated PowerShell session to ensure that the latest PowerShellGet is
> loaded.
>
> ```
> Install-Module PowerShellGet -Force -AllowClobber
> ```
>
> **To install Teams PowerShell public preview, run the PowerShell command below.**
>
> You can find the latest preview version at PowerShell Gallery or in
> PowerShell by running "Find-Module MicrosoftTeams -AllowPrerelease"
>
> ```
> Install-Module MicrosoftTeams -AllowPrerelease -RequiredVersion "1.1.3-preview"
> ```

(1.1.5) is the latest preview version as for 2020-09-16).

Comment: I have tried to Get-Module commands. 
I am able to see that the module got loaded. Also I can see all the commands like Get-Teams etc.. except the Get-TeamChannelUser

Comment: Which version(s) do you have installed?